# Instead of a symbol, it supplies a question mark in Apache POI

Tags: kotlin, apache-poi

I want to write ,  or the same country symbols, but when I open *.docx file created by code, there two question symbols
[image: Question symbol instead country symbol]

- "\uD83C\uDDFA\uD83C\uDDFF"

Other symbols also so. For example ,

My code :

```
override fun write(file: File, strings: List<ProductDto>): Boolean {

    val document = XWPFDocument()
    val out = FileOutputStream(file)

    val paragraph = document.createParagraph()

    strings.forEach {
        createRun(paragraph, it.countryTitle ?: "")
        createRun(paragraph, it.product ?: "")
        createRun(paragraph, it.weightOfProduct ?: "")
        createRun(paragraph, it.exportTime ?: "")
        val splittedAdditional = it.additional?.split("\n")
        for (str in (splittedAdditional?.toList() ?: listOf())) {
            createRun(paragraph, str)
        }
        paragraph.createRun().apply {
            addBreak()
        }
    }

    document.write(out)
    out.close()

    return true
}

private fun createRun(paragraph:XWPFParagraph, text:String) {
    val run = paragraph.createRun()
    run.setText(text)
    run.fontSize = 14
    run.addBreak()
}
```

Comment: Does your font support those characters? If you put those into a document in Word and read it back through Apache POI, how does Word opt to store the characters in the file?

Comment: what version of POI and xmlbeans are you using? There used to be a bug in xmlbeans where it added ASCII '?' char if the characters were surrogate pairs - https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/XMLBEANS-332